# How to setup mongo replica set in dokku?

Tags: mongodb, dokku

I'm using [dokku-mongo](https://github.com/dokku/dokku-mongo) but can't find a way to setup a replica set. It only creates a standalone mongo database.

Kindly help. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

In issue [#110](https://github.com/dokku/dokku-mongo/issues/110) the maintainer of dokku-mongo, [josegonzalez](https://github.com/josegonzalez), states that replica sets are out of the scope of dokku-mongo.

However, some users have been able to get replica sets working manually and explain their process in issue [#88](https://github.com/dokku/dokku-mongo/issues/88)